# how to display object values inside a form in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to display individual value of json object into form in angular. How to do that?

**output**

```
{
  "Order": {
    "active": true,
    "Orders_Entrydate": "2017-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
    "LastTouchDateTime": "2018-05-10T05:46:38.702Z",
    "_id": "5af07544eb26f918e0e2ff74",
    "Orders_Name": "Test1",
    "Orders_Number": "1011",
    "Orders_LoanNumber": 1328,
    "Orders_PropertyAddress1": "test address1",
    "Orders_PropertyAddress2": "test address 1",
    "Orders_PropertyCity": "testCity",
    "Orders_Propertyzipecode": 1236,
    "Orders_Countyfee": 500,
    "Orders_Additionalfee": 100,
    "Orders_Customerpricing": 150
  }
}
```

**view-order.ts**

```
export class countyViewOrderComponent implements OnInit {
  orders: any[];

  constructor(private orderService: countyvieworder, private router: Router, private cookie_service: CookieService) {

  }
  getorder() {
    this.orderService.getOrders().subscribe(response => {
      this.orders = response.json();


    })
  }


  onSelect(selectedItem: any) {
    this.cookie_service.put('key', selectedItem._id)
    // this.cookie_service.get('key')
    this.router.navigate(['pages/home/County/orderEntrybyCounty']);


  }



  ngOnInit() {

    this.getorder()


  }


}
```

**getOrderbyOrderNo() service**

```
getOrderbyOrderNo() {
        this.id = this.cookie_service.get('key');
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/View/'+ this.id)

    }
```

Getting this error:

> Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string'.

​

Comment: Please share `orderService.getOrderbyOrderNo()` code as well. There is a type mismatch. What is the type of the response being returned by `getOrderByOrderNo?`

Comment: getOrderbyOrderNo() {
        this.id = this.cookie_service.get('key');
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/View/'+ this.id)
       
    }

Comment: Please post the whole function, including the return type, in the original post, not as a comment.

Comment: what is your `this.orders`

Comment: @rina are you using `HttpModule` or `HttpClientModule`

Comment: are you using httclient ???

Comment: can you please look answer provided by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you to make use of `HttpClient` , that will do conversation for you . HTTPClient is new module in angular which replaced old HTTP one.

import `HttpClientmodule` in your module

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
```

**change in service.ts**

```
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getOrderbyOrderNo() :Observable<any> {
        this.id = this.cookie_service.get('key');
        return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/View/'+ this.id)
    }
```

**view-order.ts**

```
 order: any;//no array as you are expecting only one element 
 getorder() {
    this.orderService.getOrders().subscribe(response => {
      this.order = response;
    })
  }
```

in your code you are using array that is also cause problem

Answer (score 1):

Change the `getorder` function `subscribe` to  `subscribe((response: any))`

```
getorder() {
    this.orderService.getOrderbyOrderNo().subscribe((response: any) => {    
         console.log(response);          
        this.orders=response

    })
}
```

Comment: yes he might be using that, as generally everyone is using that.

Comment: but doesnt look like as its named http , and doing converstation which is not needed

Comment: yeah, `http` is `variable` name, but we dont know what he is using since he didnt mentioned anything

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing your response so here this code may be help you

```
 this.orders=JSON.parse(response);
```

or you can also do this in your service

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/View/'+ this.id).map(data => data.json());
```

Comment: what if OP is using `HttpClientModule`?

Comment: @vikas it will works fine if you use HttpClientModule

Comment: yes i'm using httpclientModule .                                                        
 import {Http, RequestOptions, Headers} from "@angular/http";  constructor(private _http: Http) {
   }

Comment: @chandrakant the new `HttpClientModule` by default formats the response to JSON so we no longer need to parse it using `response.json()`

Comment: @RajanDesai Nope your import clearly shows you are using `HttpModule`  not `HttpClientModule`

Comment: @Vikas i tried and its working in my machine and if you have any query with your code then share me so i can try it on my machine and help you to find solution

Comment: @rajan i am sure that you have first define HttpModule and then after override HttpClientModule, is it right ????

Comment: I don't have any query all I wanted to convey is `HttpModule` is deprecated if OP is using  Angular version> 4.3 then he should be using `HttpClientModue`  which by default  formats the response to `JSON` so you do not require `resposne.json()`

Comment: @Vikas i agree with you but my solution also right!!